# Image repeats when inserting Firestore data

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I've created a small "notification-center" in a tableview. But somehow the image is repeating itself, and that's not the way it should be.

I can't really figure out the reason for this by my own, so I'm asking you guys for some help.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let listPath = list[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ListCell") as! HistoryCell
    cell.setCell(list: listPath) 

    print(cell.note.text!)

     //THIS ONE
    if cell.note.text!.isEmpty == false
    {
        cell.noteImg.isHidden = false
    }


    return cell
}
```

This is parts of the code I've. So let me explain how this actually works.

Every time a user added data to a SPECIFIC textfield it should be added in "notes" in Firestore.
I select everything from Firestore to insert the data into this `UITableView`, and IF "notes" is not empty. My image should be visible.

The result I get now:
It will add repeatedly even with value is nil.

[image: img]

So as you can see on the picture.
The first (1) is correct. (The one at 12:55)
but the second one should NOT be there, it's just added randomly.

I really hope you understand, wasn't too easy to keep it short and organized.

---

**Edit:**

```
 func setCell(list: listTxt){
    DogName.text = list.dog
    Person.text = list.person
    Action.text = list.action
    Date.text = list.date
    Time.text = list.time
    timer.text = list.timer
    kilometer.text = list.kilometers
    documentID.text = list.documentID
    latitude = list.latitude
    longitude = list.longitude
    note.text = list.note
    noteImg.image = list.noteImg
}
```

Comment: please post content of setCell method

Comment: @iMHiteshSurani There you go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure but according to my knowledge and experience below code cause unexpected output.

`cell.note.text!.isEmpty == false`

`UITableView` is populating data by `reusing` the `UITableViewCell`. That's why you are getting unexpected output.

Just replace `cellForRowAt` method with my code. I hope it will work.

**Code:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let listPath = list[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ListCell") as! HistoryCell
    cell.setCell(list: listPath) 

    if listPath.note.isEmpty == false{
        cell.noteImg.isHidden = false
    }else{
        cell.noteImg.isHidden = true
    }
    return cell
}
```

## Update:

## dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)

> Returns a reusable table-view cell object for the specified reuse
>   identifier and adds it to the table.

Reference: [dequeueReusableCell](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614878-dequeuereusablecell)

Comment: @Putte LOL...It is all about the experience. Anyway, you can refer it https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614878-dequeuereusablecell. If you really want to understand the exact issue.